# var_dump array using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, var-dump

I have a bunch of arrays that I'd like to var_dump. These arrays are named based off of a $_GET from a form, so each are different but have a pre defined name attached to the start so I might have `array_bob`, `array_mary`, `array_sam` where bob mary and sam is the $_GET value.

I thought using `preg_match` would  be my best bet but I just don't know how to go about doing it

I thought something like this but it obviously doesn' work

> ```
>           if (isset($array_(preg_match("/[A-Z]|[0-9]/i",$array_))))
>           {   
>               var_dump($array_(preg_match("/[A-Z]|[0-9]/i",$array_)))
>           }
> ```

Basically, what I need is a wild card at the end of array_* to dump mary, bob and sue.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are the key/values in your $_GET data?

Comment: @MattDiamant it would be like "name"=>$_GET['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the arrays are in the GLOBAL object, right? So you can do this:

```
$arrayName = "array_" . $_GET['name'];
var_dump($GLOBALS[$arrayName]);
```

Although, a better way to do this would be to have all of the array_bob, array_mary, etc. arrays as indices in one array, so you don't have to deal with the GLOBAL object. Something like this:

```
$allArrays = array("mary" => array_mary, "bob" => array_bob);
$name = $_GET['name'];
var_dump($allArrays[$name]);
```

Comment: Didn't think to put all arrays into an array. This has made life much easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this ??

```
$arrName = $_GET['name'];
print_r(${'array_' . $arrName});
```

or this ?

```
$nameArray = array('bob', 'mary', 'sam');

foreach ($nameArray as $arrName) {
  if (isset(${'array_' . $arrName})) {
    print_r(${'array_' . $arrName});
  }
}
```

Comment: Kind of. Becuase I have a lot of arrays I'd like to dump them all and the $arrName = $_GET['name']; only gets the latest $_GET value.

Comment: Thanks, the foreach loop is exactly what I was after.